# What might be the consequences of not declaring foreign student debt when applying for a mortgage abroad?

Tags: united-kingdom, international, debt, students

When moving to a foreign country I know of many people who have decided not to declare their foreign (United Kingdom) student debt. What might be the consequences for doing so and how might a provider legally go about finding about such debt? I'm interested in answers directly about the Netherlands or similar EU countries.

Comment: As with many questions, the answer is likely to depend on which country "abroad" is.

Comment: @TomRevell I updated my question to include the Netherlands and or similar EU countries.

Answer (score 2):

### Worst case - you go to jail

Technically, obtaining a loan by lying is fraud in every jurisdiction I know about. If it turned out you were unable to pay and investigation showed you had lied, the lender might report you to the police who might charge you.